# How to install educational software meta-packages on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, edubuntu, metapackages

I have realized that edubuntu is no longer available for recent Ubuntus, and that the projects has been somehow replaced by [ubuntued](https://fossbytes.com/ubuntued-20-04-new-educational-linux-distros-for-kids-college-students/).
Ubuntued seems to provide the following bundle of packages (in form of meta-packages):

- ubuntued-meta-preschool
- ubuntued-meta-primary
- ubuntued-meta-secondary
- ubuntued-meta-tertiary

As ubuntued seems to be based on Ubuntu, I assume to find and install these packages on my Ubuntu 20.04 all I need to do, instead of installing ex-novo ubuntued, is to add their repositories. But which are those?

Alternatively, are there available "just" some curated meta-packages for the "standard" Ubuntu?

Comment: The link you provided lists the individual applications, which are all already in the Ubuntu repositories. You don't need to install a specific respin of Ubuntu, you don't need to add any non-stock repositories, and you don't need the meta-packages. Simply look at the list and install what you want to use: `sudo apt install package1 package2 package3`. It's really that easy.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciated the answers. However I feel a bit odd that the question has been labelled "off topic" because "is not about an official Ubuntu flavor", as it is clearly stated I am trying to find the solution using "standard ubuntu"... it seems around StackExchange sites there are more and more people whose primary satisfaction is to close questions...

Comment: Voting to reopen: Your primary question is seems to be "*How do I add the ubuntued repositories to a 20.04 system*?" which seems [on-topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) to me. Were it about installing ubuntued, that would be off-topic. Consider a minor edit to emphasize that your question is about an Ubuntu 20.04 system.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's needlessly confusing now that Edubuntu has been resurrected in 23.04. [Release Notes](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/edubuntu-23-04-released/35281)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still can get [Educational packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=education) on any release of Ubuntu. They are named:

- Package `astro-education`

  > Educational astronomy applications
- Package `ezgo-education`

  > Debian EzGo Education
- Package `games-education`

  > Debian's educational games
- Package `junior-education`

  > Debian Jr. education applications
- Package `kdeedu`

  > educational applications from the official KDE release

---

If you want to get some new taste of Ubuntu in education, then check [Linux L-i-f-e](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cyberorg-home/files/Li-f-e/) (Linux for Education based on Ubuntu MATE).

Comment: This is a great list of the metapackages for educational apps, but Edubuntu is back now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this answer can be changed now: [Edubuntu is back!](https://www.edubuntu.org/)

Furthermore, there are metapackages for each age level:

- Package `ubuntu-edu-preschool`

> Preschool age level

- Package `ubuntu-edu-primary`

> Primary/Elementary age level

- Package `ubuntu-edu-secondary`

> Secondary/Middle/High School age level

- Package `ubuntu-edu-tertiary`

> Tertiary/College/University age level

I hope this helps!